# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am creating an spring boot Batch application. That Batch loads data from postgres and insert into MongoDB. I have written the code , but while running the spring boot application, its shows error that `application.properties` file is not found. below are error snippets:

```
'Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.batch.SpringBatchExample]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Below are `application.properties` file contents:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=Test_Data

#logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
logging.level.=ERROR
logging.level.com.mastercard.refdata.*=DEBUG


#By default, Spring runs all the job as soon as it has started its context.
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

#Chunk Size to save data
spring.chunk.size=200

#Postgres DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Company-Test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=test123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Please let me know why I am getting this issue??

Comment: Please post the code you have written, or a minimal, verifiable example of the code. 
Also, please format your question so it is more readable.

Comment: Make sure the `application.properties` file is in your classpath. If you use maven, it should be in `src/main/resources` directory.

Comment: Post your project structure screenshot.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue although all configurations where all right. after a long time I just used *mvn clean package* command and everything was fine.

Comment: that fixed it for me too while everything else didn't! :)

Comment: This suggestion helped me get rid of a similar error. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

1. Check that your application.properties file is in the resources directory as picture shown below:
   [image]
2. If you keep your application.properties to other folder (e.g config) as shown in below picture then configure your pom.xml following code:

   ```
   <build>
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>config</directory>
           <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
           <includes>
               <include>application.properties</include>
           </includes>
       </resource>
     </resources>
   </build>
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I have renamed the properties file but forgot to change in the pom file. You saved my time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Mark it as root resource.

Here is how it's done in intellij:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

configure your pom.xml file add resources;

```
 <build>
        <finalName>your-project-name</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use IntelliJ Idea

[If you declared your classpath like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOatA.png)

```
@PropertySource("classpath:sport.properties")
public class SportConfig {
 //some code
}
```

[Then you Should add your properties file to the resources directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDAGS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `application.properties` file to the resources directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the **config** path (projectBaseName\target\local\config) in the Bootstrap tab in Run Configuration, because all the properties file are placed in the classpath.[image: You can follow bellow picture for the same]

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was to re-add the library (project which is a dependency in my case for my main project) to the assembly deployement of the main project I am working on. For some reason Eclipse was not able to detect this project in its class path.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvTk.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this on configuration class

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

(OR)

Use this in xml file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using classpath:filepath inside @sql annotation of @sqlgroup use
file:filepath
It makes java search through the entire folder searching for a file of similar path,worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this also happens when you have opened your project in multiple IDEs. For example, Eclipse does not recognize the configuration files of other IDEs.

If this happens in Eclipse, what we can do is go to project -> "clean..." option. This will clean the build files and re-build the project.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

properties file location: `src/student-info.properties`

I imported successfully like below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:src/student-info.properties"/>

    <bean id="student" class="com.Student">
        <property name="name" value="${student.name}"/>
        <property name="hobby" value="${student.interestedCourse}"/>
        <property name="interestedCourse" value="${student.hobby}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse IDE
You should create a "resources" folder inside src. Then It will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in case of switching from/to `.yml and/or .properties` file,  you might have to also check if you have explicitly mentioned which properties(.properties or .yml) file you explicitly mentioned in configuration file.
Search `application.properties` or `.yml` and look for `@PropertiesSource` value if it is mentioned in there

Answer (score 0):

Run commands mentioned below one by one -

1. "mvn clean"
2. "mvn clean install -am -pl  -DskipTests"

Go to your project refresh and build.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using [this file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK9HT.png)

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
    Student student1 = (Student) context.getBean("student1");
    System.out.println(student1); // override toString()
  }
}
```

Output:

> Hello World!
> Student{studentId=2233, studentName='Rahul', studentAddress='Chennai'}

Answer (score 0):

You may need to export a profile in order for spring-boot to find it's config props.

```
 export spring_profiles_active=local
```

Check what profiles are defined for the project.

Answer (score -1):

My issue is the same. You're trying to connect multiple databases in your project.

In Main Application Run have an Annotation like:

```
{ { {@PropertySources({@PropertySource("/../resources/datasource_cfg.properties")})}
```

It's the path to parse when the application is run. Maybe your path isn't correct.